# Map.onClick to map list

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to create a map inspector on a split-panel view. The idea is to get the coordinates (or other map info) when clicking any of the maps in the panels.

The following piece makes the job Panel by panel.

```
// panels to hold lon/lat values
var lon = ui.Label();
var lat = ui.Label();
var panel = ui.Panel()
panel.add(ui.Panel([ui.Label('coords: '),lon, lat], ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal')));
panel.style().set({border: '5px solid darkgray'})
side_panel.add(panel)

var maplist = [map0,map1,map2,map3,map4,map5,map6]

// Register a callback on the default map to be invoked when the map is clicked
maplist[0].onClick(function(coords) {
  // Update the lon/lat panel with values from the click event.
  lon.setValue('lon: ' + coords.lon.toFixed(2)),
  lat.setValue('lat: ' + coords.lat.toFixed(2));
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat)});
```

However, since I have multiple maps it would be useful to apply the `onClick` to a list of maps in one go, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I realized it is possible to apply `forEach` to the list of linked maps:

```
var maplist = [map0,map1,map2,map3,map4,map5,map6]

// link the maps
var linker = ui.Map.Linker(maplist)

// apply the function for each of the linked maps
linker.forEach(function(map){map.onClick(function(coords) {
  // Update the lon/lat panel with values from the click event.
  lon.setValue('lon: ' + coords.lon.toFixed(2)),
  lat.setValue('lat: ' + coords.lat.toFixed(2));
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat)});})
```